# How to cast Geometry to Geography in PostGIS/Postgres with sqlalchemy + geoalchemy

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geoalchemy

Some PostGIS functions behave differently based on the arguments types.

Example: [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) will calculate projected units distances for [`geometry`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html) arguments and meters distances for [`geography`](https://postgis.net/docs/geography.html) arguments.

In PostgreSQL you can easily cast with the `::` [syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/catalog-pg-cast.html), but what if you are using sqlalchemy objects or geoalchemy?

Comment: Useful WKT/WKB/GeoJSON converter [online tool](https://rodic.fr/blog/online-conversion-between-geometric-formats/)

Answer (score 4):

Here are two ways of casting in python, when a table has a [Geometry](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#geoalchemy2.types.Geometry) column.

## Given

```
from geoalchemy2 import Geometry
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import (Column, Integer)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SRS_WGS_84 = 4326

ClassBase = declarative_base()

class MyTable(ClassBase):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    geometry = Column(Geometry(srid=SRS_WGS_84, management=True))

LOCAL_TEST_DB = "postgresql+psycopg2:///my_test_db"
DB_ECHO = False

engine = create_engine(LOCAL_TEST_DB, echo=DB_ECHO)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
```

## 1. Casting with Geoalchemy

```
from geoalchemy2.types import Geography
from sqlalchemy.sql import cast

record1_geography = session.query(cast(MyTable.geometry, Geography(srid=SRS_WGS_84))
                                 ).filter(MyTable.id == 1).one()
```

## 2. Casting with PostGIS [support function](https://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_Curved_GeometryFunctions)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

cast(models.Task.geometry, Geography(srid=SRID))

# ref: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeogFromWKB.html
record1_geography_2 = session.query(func.ST_GeogFromWKB(MyTable.geometry)
                                   ).filter(MyTable.id == 1).one()
```